# Couldn't find a 'component' or 'children' prop for the screen 'Home'

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm trying to use react-navigate v5 to setup a stacknavigator for some screens. Currently I'm getting this error while trying to run the app:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/moTT0.png)

My App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import SignIn from './App/Screens';

const AuthStack = createStackNavigator();

export default () => (
  <NavigationContainer>
    <AuthStack.Navigator>
      <AuthStack.Screen name='SignIn' component = {SignIn} />
    </AuthStack.Navigator>
  </NavigationContainer>
);
```

my Screens.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text, StyleSheet, Button, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        padding: 20,
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
    input: {
        height: 40,
        backgroundColor: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)",
        marginBottom: 10,
        color: '#FFF',
        paddingHorizontal: 10
    },
    buttonContainer: {
        backgroundColor: '#2980b9',
        paddingVertical: 10,
        marginBottom: 10

    },
    buttonText: {
        textAlign: 'center',
        color: '#FFF',
        fontWeight: '700'
    }
});

const ScreenContainer = ({ children }) => (
    <View style={styles.container}>{children}</View>
  );
export const SignIn = ({ navigation }) => {  
    return (
      <ScreenContainer>
        <Text>Sign In Screen</Text>
        <Button title="Sign In" onPress={() => alert("todo") } />
        <Button
          title="Create Account"
          onPress={() => alert("todo")}
        />
      </ScreenContainer>
    );
  };
```

Not sure what's going on, would appreciate some help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your import from, as you are using a named export

```
import SignIn from './App/Screens';
```

to

```
import {SignIn} from './App/Screens';
```